# SQL Update varchar to date error

Tags: sql, datetime, char

I have a table with 5 million records of dates stored as char(10) with format yyyy/mm/dd. I need to convert these to datetime, so I use:

```
 UPDATE [Database].[dbo].[Table]
    SET [DoB]=convert(datetime,[DoBText],103)
 GO
```

But I get the error:

"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Now, I've tried fixing the data so this doesn't happed - i.e. no "yyyy" below 1900 or above 2000, no "dd" above 30 (28 for Feb), no "mm" above 12 or below 0. No NULLs.

Still the conversion fails.

Is there any way I can let SQL to skip the conversion on an error and just go on?

E.g. something like:

```
  SET [DoB]= try to do [DoB]=convert(datetime,[DoBText],103) if fails SET [DoB] = NULL
```

Thanks
Karl

Comment: Some months have 31 days in - I hope you haven't broken your data :S

Comment: Also, there is no month zero - month should be 1-12 inclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SET DATEFORMAT YMD;

UPDATE [Database].[dbo].[Table]
SET [DoB]=[DoBText]
WHERE ISDATE( [DoBText] ) = 1
```

This will convert those that are recognised as valid date/time values, the rest will be left as-is.

Answer (score 1):

The conversion style 103 handles a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy. Use the conversion style 111 instead to handle the format yyyy/mm/dd.

Answer (score 0):

insert the date in yyyyMMdd format or use parameters and you won't have this problem.
or do one of the following

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
SET DATEFORMAT MDY
SET DATEFORMAT YMD
SET DATEFORMAT YDM
```